# GeoTIFF compression on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I'm using GeoServer to provide maps generated from raster data (satellite imagery from Sentinel) to a web application via WMS layers.
Each raster consists of a file of about 1.8-2 gb. To save space on disk I tried to apply a `gdal_translate` using some compression algorithms.

I tried a simple `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" infile.tif outfile.tif`.
Input GTiff file is obtained by extracting RGB band from the L2A source. Using JPEG compression each file reduces the dimensions to less than 500 mb. 
Testing the web application (built using OpenLayers) I noticed a marked deterioration of performance in terms of speed and responsiveness. 
Is the problem due to the computation required to GeoServer to process a compressed file? Is there a better solution among the compression methods provided by GDAL or the best possible performance requires a non-compressed raster?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Please add the gdal_translate command that you used. You may have turned a tiled tiff into striped one. Missing overviews can also make much bigger difference than uncompressed vs. compressed does.